# How to make a x y line plot with python?

Tags: python, pandas, plot

Hello I have the following dataframe:

```
df = [{'Column1': 1, 'Colunm2': 'A', 'Colunm3': 2}, 
      {'Column1': 2, 'Colunm2': 'A', 'Colunm3': 4},
      {'Column1': 3, 'Colunm2': 'A', 'Colunm3': 1},
      {'Column1': 1, 'Colunm2': 'B', 'Colunm3': 7},
      {'Column1': 2, 'Colunm2': 'B', 'Colunm3': 2},
      {'Column1': 3, 'Colunm2': 'B', 'Colunm3': 9}]
```

How can I make a X Y plot between `Column1` and `Colunm3` but plotting two diffentent lines, one for values `Colunm2 = 'A'` and other for values `Colunm2 ='B'`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What tools are you using? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df)
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
for i,g in df1.groupby('Colunm2'):
    g.plot('Column1','Colunm3',ax=ax,label=i)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a more versatile answer taking advantage of the fact that plotting is specifically implemented for [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.plot.html) objects.  The only shortcoming in my view (of pandas, not of the answer) is that you should be able to pass a list of labels in one call to `.plot`, i.e. `g.plot('Column1','Colunm3',ax=ax,label=['A', 'B'])`.

Comment: @BradSolomon You can do this exactly that with Seaborn using the `hue` parameter.

Comment: with `sns.lmplot`?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @ScottBoston in his comment there is also `sns.pointplot` where the `hue` parameter is effectively a groupby.

```
import sns.apiponly as sns
sns.pointplot('Column1', 'Colunm3', data=DataFrame(df), hue='Colunm2')
plt.ylabel('Colunm3')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = [{'Column1': 1, 'Colunm2': 'A', 'Colunm3': 2},
      {'Column1': 2, 'Colunm2': 'A', 'Colunm3': 4},
      {'Column1': 3, 'Colunm2': 'A', 'Colunm3': 1},
      {'Column1': 1, 'Colunm2': 'B', 'Colunm3': 7},
      {'Column1': 2, 'Colunm2': 'B', 'Colunm3': 2},
      {'Column1': 3, 'Colunm2': 'B', 'Colunm3': 9}]

first = [(i["Column1"], i['Colunm3'])  for i in df if i['Colunm2'] == 'A']
second = [(i["Column1"], i['Colunm3']) for i in df if i['Colunm2'] == 'B']


plt.plot([a for a, b in first], [b for a, b in first])
plt.plot([a for a, b in second], [b for a, b in second])

plt.show()
```